# Working with empty object in template, how to avoid NullPointerException?

Tags: templates, scala, playframework-2.0

In Play 1.2, I use to do something like `${myobj?.item?.subitem}`.

I tried this in Play 2.0, but without any luck. Is there an possible alternative?

Comment: In Scala the use of `null` is discouraged; `Option` is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: sorry I think I have not translated this faithfully, and it's uglier. `myobj.item` could also be null so you'd have to wrap it in `Option(_)`:

```
@Option(myobj).flatMap(i => Option(i.item)).flatMap(s => Option(s.subitem)).getOrElse("empty")
```

or

```
@((for {o <- Option(myobj)
        item <- Option(o.item)
        subitem <- Option(item.subitem)
   }).getOrElse("empty"))
```

Note sure if playframework has some additional sugar for such a common case.

Comment: Using the first example, I got a "type mismatch; found : models.MyModel required: Option[?]" at `_.item` (starting after the dot). In the second example, you forgot the `}` :)

Comment: But if I replace `.flatMap` by just `.map`, it works! Do you know why and what is the difference?